# CakePHP Tree Behavior - products has more than one category

Tags: cakephp, tree

How rebuild table 'products' with actually field 'category_id', when I use Tree Behavior, to for one products belongs to more than one category?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to use a [habtm](http://book.cakephp.org/view/83/hasAndBelongsToMany-HABTM) join with a categories_products table instead of a single category_id in the product table

```
products               categories_products            categories
-------------          -------------------------      ---------------------
id | name| ..          id|category_id|product_id      id|name|parent_id|...
```